# Accessing Private Members of a class outside the class

Tags: c++

I have defined two classes as follows:-

```
class DayStat
{
private:
    double cases, deaths;
public:
    DayStat();
    DayStat(int _cases, int _deaths);
    DayStat(const DayStat &d, double denominator);
    double mortalityRate() const;
    double getcases() const;
    double getdeaths() const;
};

class Region
{
private:
    DayStat *raw;
    char *name;
    int population;
    int area;
    int nday;
};
```

Now, I want to store the cases and deaths of the DayStat class which are private into the raw dynamic array being defined in the Region class. That is raw should store the cases and deaths of a region. But, I am not sure how to access the 2 private members (cases and deaths) from the DayStat class in the Region class. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: What are `getcases` and `getdeaths` for? I don;t see the problem. If you post some code where your tried to access this data (and it failed for some reason) then I might have a better idea of what the problem is.

Comment: @john  These are to return the cases and deaths

Comment: @john But, I can't modify their values, right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. So the next question is why do you want to modify the values?

Comment: @john I want to store the values of cases and deaths in raw array

Comment: if you want to  modify ther values then create set functions

Comment: That doesn't require modifying the values.

Comment: Use the constructor to give the values you require.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this

```
raw[10] = DayStat(20, 30);
```